# Unable to connect to Google domains

Tags: ubuntu, internet-connection

I'm using Ubuntu 11.10 as my primary O.S. and I was browsing the net perfectly and especially Google+, suddenly without any reason any Google site (Plus, Code, Developer, GMail, etc) stopped working. They are taking a long time to respond.

This is only happening to Google sites; all the other sites works perfectly. I tried to empty the cache but no luck. I thought maybe the it was my internet connection but when when I switched to Windows 7, everything worked fine. What could be causing this?

- My Internet connection: 24.0MB ADSL.
- Multi O.S. Windows 7 and Ubuntu 11.10.
- New Laptop.

Comment: I formatted my PC for this issue but that didn't resolve the issue. The weird thing happen when I login using gmail account or my google apps account (bashar@ayyash.info), they work perfectly without signing in but when I sign in, google domains stop responding and google chrome issue: No data received
Unable to load the webpage because the server sent no data.
Here are some suggestions:
Reload this webpage later.
Error 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE): The server closed the connection without sending any data.

I don't want to go back to windows platform, pls. help!!!